# Cassandra DELETE using multi-partition BATCH vs IN operator

Tags: cassandra

We have a table where we need to process a group of deletes atomically (spread across partition keys). Would it be preferable to do with with a `LOGGED BATCH` of separate `DELETE` statements, or one `DELETE` with the keys to be deleted given in a `WHERE ... IN (...)` clause?

Answer (score 1):

None of those solutions is optimal (`BATCH`, `IN`), depending on your queries the load is moved from your clients to the coordinator nodes. You want to use parallel queries at client side if possible to distribute the load across nodes.

Now, some insights for question regarding `BATCH` and `IN`:

- In both case you want to limit the number of statements per group (~20 ish)
- If you want to group deletes, try to delete the largest block like one-go partition (to create partition-level tombstones).
- Logged batch will retry failed statements until batch timeout, it could create more load at the coordinator nodes than `IN`. The atomicity is only ensure at partition level, if you use cross partitions delete use `IN`.

Comment: I realize this is not ideal, though hopefully these operations are infrequent, e.g. as performed at a human scale by an administrator of the system, and not constant load.

My impression from reading https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlBatch.html is that `BATCH` can achieve isolation on a single partition, while a `LOGGED BATCH` is for atomicity across multiple partitions.

Comment: Is the `DELETE` with `IN` not atomic across multiple partitions? The query is marked idempotent, and we're using the java-driver client for Cassandra - perhaps similar atomicity to `LOGGED BATCH` could be achieved simply by retrying the failed `DELETE` - if a failure of one fails the entire statement?

Comment: Actually, if our solution to acheive "atomicity" is to just keep retrying until all `DELETE`s succeed, maybe then we could bypass both of these mechanism, and actually do individual parallel queries instead - keeping track of individual failures at the client level, instead of making the coordinator do that?